# Why is the melting point of water independent of pressure?

Tags: pressure, material-science, phase-transition

I've read [here](https://www.quora.com/Define-melting-point-and-boiling-point-What-is-the-difference) that the boiling point of water is highly dependent on the pressure, whereas the melting point is independent of the pressure. Why is that? Is that true in general?

Comment: Are you sure about that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point#/media/File:Phase-diag2.svg

Comment: While this isn't strictly true (see e.g. these [phase diagrams for water and carbon dioxide](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/chemistry/environmental/lectures/week2.pdf)), it is true that the liquid-vapor phase transition temperature depends on pressure much more strongly than does the solid-liquid transition temperature. Whether this extends to other materials, and whether there's a simple explanation, makes for an interesting question.

Comment: That link also says "The melting point of a substance depends on pressure and is usually specified at standard pressure." That seems to be contradictory, unless some distinction is being made between "pressure"  and "external pressure". Pressure does affect melting; for instance, ice skaters' weight melts the ice.

Comment: @Acccumulation Not sure where you see a contradiction. They say that the melting point *does* depend on pressure, but if you see "ice melts at 0 °C" without the pressure specified, it probably means "ice melts at 0 °C at standard atmospheric pressure".

Comment: @Luaan Are you thinking that I see a contradiction *within* the passage I quoted? I see a contradiction *between* that passage and them elsewhere saying melting point is independent of pressure.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because of the Clausius-Clapeyron equation
$$\frac{d \log T}{d \log P} = \frac{P \Delta V}{L}$$
where $T$ is the temperature of the phase transition, $\Delta V$ is the change in volume, and $L$ is the latent heat. The water/gas transition has an enormous $\Delta V$ because gas is much less dense than water, so $dT/dP$ is large. The water/ice transition has a $\Delta V$ about $10^{-3}$ as big, so $dT/dP$ is small.

Intuitively, there is some 'cost' $L$ to be paid doing the phase transition, and usually most of it is paid by thermal energy. But if the volume changes during the transition, the $P \Delta V$ work can also help, lowering the necessary temperature. So it makes sense that $dT/dP$ depends on the ratio of these two contributions.